# How to hide the dismiss button (x) when presenting a .sheet in watchOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-10

I use a .sheet to present a workout UI during a workout.  WatchOS 10 seems to have added a dismiss button ("X") in the top left corner out of the box to a view presented via `.sheet`.  How can I hide it?  It was suggested to use a `.cancellationAction` with an empty view to hide it but this doesn't work.  Any other ways I can remove the dismiss button?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isShowingSheet: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            Button {
                isShowingSheet = true
            } label: {
                Text("Show Sheet")
            }
            
        }
    }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, content: {
            //NavigationStack {  //adding doesn't change 
                VStack {
                    Text("Sheet Content")
                    
                }
          //  }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.red.gradient)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("button tapped")
                    }, label: {
                        EmptyView() //Doesn't hide dismiss button
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: If you wrap the `LiveWorkoutTabView` and its toolbar modifier in a `NavigationStack`, does that help?

Comment: Another option is to not use `.sheet`, but wrap your whole navigation in a `NavigationStack`. Start your workout using a `NavigationLink`, which pushes the view onto the stack; by default the icon in the top leading space will be a back button but you can hide that with `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden()`

Comment: @ScottM thanks but no, it's parent view is already in a NavigationStack but also adding another doesn't change the behavior.  Understood about using a navigation flow instead of a .sheet but didn't want to have to redesign this part of the app just to get rid of this button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by introducing the `NavigationView` and then you can hide the navigation bar with the "X" button by using `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)`:

```
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, content: {
            NavigationView { // <-- 1
                VStack {
                    Text("Sheet Content")
                }
            }
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar) // <-- 2
            // .frame(..)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to figure this out for a month! 

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer hides the `navigationBar` as well which for scrolling content might not be ideal (as the material background is lost and content will collide with the time/status bar).

Instead, try using the `.toolbar` modifier and replacing the `cancellationAction` position, as suggested in [the HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sheets#watchOS).

```swift
.toolbar(content: {
   /// Remove the (x) on watchOS 10
   ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
      Button("", action: {}).opacity(0.0).disabled(true)
   }
})
```